# Rake db:drop not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have unseen duplicate relations and tables and I am trying to destroy my entire DB and reset out of pure frustration, and I can't even do that.  When I run rake db:drop or reset, everything is still there in my schema and migrations. How do I kill this entire DB and build it over again?

Comment: Which environment's database are you trying to drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
rake db:rollback STEP=100
```

That will revert the last 100 migrations (so take you to zero state)

Comment: I get this : Alexander$ rake db:rollback STEP=100
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "Hook_development" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database. Does this mean the drop worked? If so, why is it still in my schema and migrations?

Comment: Ah, right... the db:drop will drop the database but leave your schma intact.  Run rake db:migrate to create the database (sqlite3?) and then do the rollback to get your schema reversed.

Comment: I was able to get everything working luckily without destroying it all with the db:create db:migrate.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

While they are closely related, `migration files`/`schema.rb` are not the same thing as the database. `rake db:drop` doesn't delete the migration files or the schema because people may wish to easily recreate their entire database while maintaining the information on how the database was built (ie the migration files).

If you want to start from scratch, drop the database `rake db:drop` and manually delete the migration files (schema will be overwritten when you create your new migrations).

Comment: This I did not know and appears to be the root issue. Thanks JTG.